# How to select DISTINCT of two columns from a table with condition in Yii?

Tags: select, yii

How to convert this sql statement to yii format build a model?

```
  SELECT  DISTINCT agency_id, university_id 
      FROM `tbl_universityagency` where agency_id=1
```

like this what I am missing? ,

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
        $criteria->distinct=true;            
        $criteria->condition = "agency_id=".$result->agency_id ;         
        $modal=Universityagency::model()->find($criteria);
```

Comment: $criteria->select = 'agency_id, university_id';

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria();
$criteria->distinct=true;
$criteria->condition = "agency_id=".$result->agency_id ;      
$criteria->select = 'id, agency_id, university_id';
$modal=Universityagency::model()->find($criteria);
```

Should produce query:

```
SELECT  DISTINCT id,agency_id, university_id FROM `tbl_universityagency` where agency_id=1 LIMIT 1
```

Comment: neeed Limit=0    not Limit=1

Answer (score 4):

You have to use `findAll()` instead of `find()`.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution!

Place the below code in your Model file.

```
$criteria = new CDbCriteria;
$criteria->distinct = true;
$criteria->condition = "t.C = t.D";                
$criteria->group = "t.A";
```

Let us know if you face any query/concern regarding this.

Thanks!